# Passing Data from node js to html

Tags: html, node.js

I am connecting to an authentication server which is returning the credentials and calling to my call back method. How do I pass the authenticated values back to the html to render?

Here is my code

```
function getHomePage()
{
   // alert("here in ajax call")

    $.ajax({
        url: "/calloidcServer",
        headers:{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':['https://localhost:3000','https://localhost:9031'],
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        type: "GET",
        
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log(resp)
            
            $('#testoidc').append(resp);
        
        },
        error: function (resp, status, error) {
            
        }

    });


}



app.get("/calloidcServer",function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('-----------------------------');
  console.log('/Start login handler');
  next();

  
},
passport.authenticate('oidc',{scope:"openid"})
)

app.get('/callback',(req,res,next) =>{

  console.log(" call back from auth server here")
passport.authenticate('oidc',{ successRedirect: '/user',
failureRedirect: '/' })(req, res, next)


  }
)

app.get ("/user",(req,res) =>{
  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');

  var id_token_decode=jwt_decoder(req.session.tokenSet.id_token);
  var decoded = jwt_decoder(req.session.tokenSet.access_token); 
  console.log(id_token_decode)
  console.log(decoded);
  console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/public/citizenHome.html'))
 
  res.redirect("/citizenHome.html")
  //res.send(JSON.stringify({tokenset:req.session.tokenSet,userinfo:req.session.userinfo},null,2));

})
```

When I redirect to citizenHome.html, I want to send back some data to it to show in the html? I have not used any view engine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can pass values to the HTML directly, but you can use any view-engine with Node.js that can help you pass values from the routes and render the page as you want.

You can use [EJS](https://ejs.co/), [JADE](https://jade-lang.com/) or [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).